# How to show a QString in a QVBoxLayout

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to put a title just before a QSLider so the user know what the QSlider is for.
I have 2 QSlider in a QDialog Box set on a QVBoxLayout like this :

```
QSlider * slider1 = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal);
QSlider * slider2 = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal);

QDialog * opts = new QDialog;
QVBoxLayout * layout = new QVBoxLayout;

layout->addWidget(Qstring("Label for Slider 1"));
layout->addWidget(slider1);
layout->addWidget(QString("Label for Slider 2"));
layout->addWidget(slider2);

opts->setLayout(layout);
opts->show();
```

Now the sliders works just fine, but I can't show the text. And I've found absolutely nothing about a thing like this, whatsoever. How can I just show a String in a QVBoxLayout ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What's wrong?

You **can't** directly add `QString` like that, since `QString` is just a convenient class for string operation and it's not responsible for UI display.

### Solution:

You need a instance of **[`QLabel`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html)** to hold your `QString`:

```
QLabel *label_1 = new QLabel(this);
label_1->setText("Label for Slider 1");
layout->addWidget(label_1);
layout->addWidget(slider1);
```

---

### Better layouts:

In addition, you may consider using [**nested layout**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502323/qt-what-layout-or-combination-of-layout-should-use-in-this-case/24502825#24502825): create a new horizontal layout that holds one `QLabel` and one `QSlider`, then add the layout into your dialog layout.

Here is the code:

```
QSlider * slider1 = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal);
QSlider * slider2 = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal);

QDialog * opts = new QDialog;
QVBoxLayout * layout = new QVBoxLayout; // layout for Dialog itself
QHBoxLayout * layout_1 = new QHBoxLayout(this); // layout for slider1 & label1
QHBoxLayout * layout_2 = new QHBoxLayout(this); // layout for slider2 & label2

QLabel *label_1 = new QLabel(this);
QLabel *label_2 = new QLabel(this);
label_1->setText("Label for Slider 1");
label_2->setText("Label for Slider 2");

layout_1->addWidget(label_1);    
layout_1->addWidget(slider1); // [Label_1][Slider1]

layout_2->addWidget(label_2);    
layout_2->addWidget(slider2); // [Label_2][Slider2]

layout->addLayout(layout_1);
layout->addLayout(layout_2);    
opts->setLayout(layout);
opts->show();
```

P.S. I strongly recommend you using designer to deploy your widget layouts.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll validate your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: The use of the designer is quite complicated with Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Oh... perhaps you can consider using Qt creator as your IDE for developing Qt widgets if Qt amazes you in the future. The ability of switching back and forth between Ui designer and codes editor is very helpful.